# No puedo acceder a los objetos que guarde en una lista en C#

Tags: c#, lista

hace poco estoy intentando aprender C# y me encontre con este problema.
- Cree una clase llamada person con algunos atributos. Lo que quiero hacer es guardar todas las "personas" que el usuario cargue al sistema en una lista para luego poder hacer cosas con esta informacion, pero cuando intento recorrer esta lista para mostrar todas las personas cargadas lo unico que arroja el sistema es lo siguiente: "el namespace del projecto".Person

Aca esta el codigo

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Clases_csharp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Person.Carga_Persona();
            Console.WriteLine("Total:" + Person.count);






        Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public static int count;

        public string date_of_birth;
        public string name,lastname;
        public string obs;
        public double CIndex;

        public Person (string _date_Of_birth,string _name,string _lastname,string _Obs,double _CIndex)
        {

            date_of_birth = _date_Of_birth;
            name = _name;
            lastname = _lastname;
            obs = _Obs;
            CIndex = _CIndex;

        }

        public static void Carga_Persona ()
        {
            List<Person> todos = new List<Person>();
                        Console.WriteLine("enter 1 to register a new person, 2 to stop");
            int des = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (des ==1) 
            {


                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Date of birth of the person");
                string date = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the name");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Last Name");
                string Last_Name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Observations about de person");
                string obs = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Index");
                double Index = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Person person1 = new Person(date,name,Last_Name,obs,Index);
                count += 1 ;
                todos.Add(person1);
            Console.WriteLine("enter 1 to register a new person, 2 to stop");
                des = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int large = todos.Count ;
            for (int i = 0; i < large; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine(todos[i]);

         }

        }

    }
}
```

Cuando corro el debugger todas las variables parecen tener los valores correctos y la lista tiene guardada todas las "Personas" que cargue.

Gracias !

Comment: por favor traduce tu pregunta ya que estas en la versión en español de SO, de otra forma será cerrada

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, tambien debes traducir el titulo

Comment: Ahi lo traduje, pense que estaba en SO en español ! perdon.

Comment: Habras querido decir en ingles ;)

Comment: Si, no estoy pegando perdon ! :( jaja

Comment: Considera usar propiedades con get y set

Answer (score 1):

Tu código tiene varios errores de concepto.

Resolvamos el problema principal, porque ves "el namespace del projecto".Person?

Esto pasa, porque le estas pidiendo exactamente eso a tu codigo.

Al hacer: `Console.WriteLine(todos[i]);` Lo que estas pidiendo es, transforma el objeto que esta en todos[i] a un string, y ponelo por pantalla. Tu objetivo, pareceria ser que de alguna forma queres imprimir los datos de la persona.

Pero lo que esta pasando ahi, es que esta ejecutando el metodo `ToString` del objeto que tratas de acceder, que en este caso es tu clase Person. Como toda clase hereda implicitamente de object, y tu clase no tiene un metodo sobrecargado `ToString()`, entonces llama al `ToString()` del objeto base, que no hace otra cosa que imprimir el tipo del objeto ([mira aca para el ver el codigo fuente del que te hablo](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,ff31a6bf27c58f89)).

Entonces, lo que necesitas, es agregar a tu objeto un metodo `ToString` ([esto esta declarado por microsoft aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method)), que le diga como transformar las propiedades del mismo a una cadena imprimible.

En tu clase person, agrega un metodo de la siguiente forma:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return name+" "+lastname;
}
```

Y dentro del mismo, devolve una cadena como queres que sea impresa. En el ejemplo de arriba, devuelve el nombre, un espacio y el apellido.

### Notas

- Tu clase person tiene casi todo el codigo para la persona? o sea, tiene el codigo principal de tu programa? Carga_persona no deberia estar ahi adentro.
- El main devuelve el count, de un objeto que nunca crece (o lo perdi en el codigo)?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta !
Tenes razon, Carga_personas no deberia esta ahi.
el count esta declarado en la clase Person, y suma cuando instancio una nueva persona!
No entendi bien que deberia ir dentro del metodo que dijiste perdon !!

Comment: De nada. Recuerda simpre como funciona el sitio, acepta respuestas cuando tengas una que sirva, y bienvenido!!! lee bien el [tour]

Comment: @Martin_C_Sharp que parte no entendiste bien? tu metodo ToString tiene que devolver un string, con lo que vos queres que se imprima. por ejemplo name+last_name; Ahora te lo agrego en la respuesta. El count tampoco deberia ser un objeto estatico adentro la clase. La clase no tiene porque saber el total de ellas creadas. el array que las contiene ya sabe el count

Comment: ahi te entendi. Gracias por  la aclaracion. Si esta mal lo del count, estoy retomando programacion con C# y aparentemente muchos conceptos basicos se me fueron olvidando! Saludos